# Php a single query always return o count

Tags: php, mysql

I use the below code to get check the log in details using php. But I can't get the result row count. The same query executed in mysql workbench and return a row.But here it's not working. Please help me to do this. Because am new for php.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);
echo "$myusername<br />";
echo "$mypassword<br />";
$sql="SELECT * FROM TBL_ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE FLD_USER='$myusername' and FLD_PASS='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);    
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
//echo "$result[0]<br />";
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
session_register("myusername");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: try `if($count> 0)` instead `if($count==1)`

Comment: `mysql_*` and `session_register` = `Deprecated`

Comment: echo $sql; and run this output in your mysql server and let us know how many rows return?

Comment: echo $count; always return zero

Comment: @AwladLiton it return a row

Comment: [`session_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) **Warning** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. (in case your PHP version falls into any of those)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);    
$active=$row['active'];
```

Or Use This Query

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM TBL_ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE FLD_USER='$myusername' and 
FLD_PASS='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);    
$count=$row['num'];
```

Or

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM TBL_ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE FLD_USER='$myusername' and FLD_PASS='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $active=$row['active'];
  $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;
  header("location: welcome.php");
}else{$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";}
```

And don't use `session_register`